# Loop with groovy to execute a TestCase in soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

i wanto run 5 times a testcase in soapui using groovy.
i found the following code in Stackoverflow and added the loop part but it executes randomly.
Sometimes it executes 2 times and sometimes 4 times.

here is the code:

```
def a = 5;
while (a>0) {
a--;

def testCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["TestCase"];  
def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap();  
def async = false;  
testCase.run(properties, async);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just wondering: why "... using groovy"? Can you not use just plain GoTo step in SoapUI?

Comment: No i don't want to use soapui steps. i want to use a groovy step.

Answer (score 0):

```
def doSomething() {
    println 'Foo Bar'
}

5.times { 
    doSomething() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you do not want to `def testCase` in your script, as `testCase` is usually defined for you.

```
def myTestCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("some TestCase")
def myContext = (com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap)context
5.times {
    myTestCase.run(myContext, false)
}
```

You also did not specify where you are doing this from. The above code will work from test suite Setup Script. If you are doing it elsewhere, you will probably need to adjust `def myTestCase`.

Comment: i don't understand how groovy knows the testsuite name

Comment: Try the documentation: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

I have following script in Setup Script of a test Suite and it is running indefinite loop:

```
 def count=context.expand('${#Global#run}')
    log.info count
    
    def project1 = runner.testCase.testSuite.project
     def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap()    
     def testcase = project1.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 1").getTestCaseByName("Login");    
     def testcase1 = project1.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 1").getTestCaseByName("Logout");    
     
   
    // This will run everything in the selected project   
    for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
     // testRunner = testcase.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)
        def myContext = (com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap)context
        testcase.run(myContext, false)
        sleep(70000)
        //testRunner = testcase1.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)
        testcase1.run(myContext, false)
        sleep(5000) 
        log.info( "Finished running "+i+" cycle" )
     if(i==count){
        testRunner.cancel('Test Execution is completed')
        break;
        }
     }
```